# Django-Registration redux password change forwards to index page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, change-password

I can use the Django-Registration redux to login and register and it works fine except for the password change which forwards to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/accounts/password/change/` which lands on the homepage.

These are my app urls:

```
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self,user):
        return('/createprofile/')

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^city/(?P<city_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.show_city, name='show_city'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', views.show_profile, name='show_profile'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registraion_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^createprofile/$', views.createprofile, name="createprofile"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the link the I use to change password:

```
<p>
    forgot your password? Ney bother.
    <a href="{% url 'excurj:auth_password_change' %}">Reset password</a>
</p>
```

This is the password_change_form.html form stored in the same place as other registration forms:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form|crispy }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the result from http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/:

[image]

EDIT: the above scenario happens when the user is not logged in. When the is logged in this error comes up:

> NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/change/ Reverse for
>   'auth_password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out that I put this:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

in the app's url.py however, it needed to be in the project's url.py.